# Getting "Error: Empty archive" when installing wine using homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, wine, xz

I am trying to install wine on my mac using homebrew following this tutorial: https://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/

In step 4 when I do "brew install wine" I get the following:

> ==> Installing wine dependency: libpng
>
> ==> Using the sandbox
>
> ==> Downloading ftp://ftp.simplesystems.org/pub/libpng/png/src/libpng16/libpng-1.6.25.tar.xz
>
> ##################################################### 100.0%
>
> Error: Empty archive

Googling around it seems that for most people who get this error it is some issue stemming from the xz package. I have tried reinstalling xz and deleting the libpng files in my Caches/Homebrew folder to force libpng to redownload. None of this has worked. Any ideas for what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I posted an issue on the Github page for homebrew and the problem comes from the new Xcode 8 on ElCapitan. They have updated homebrew to fix the problem. Running `brew update && brew reinstall xz`fixed the issue for me after the update. Here is a link to a discussion of the issue on the Github website: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/969